# Changing linetype and line color with plot_model()

Tags: r, ggplot2, sjplot

I am trying to create a plot of predicted values using the `plot_model()` function from `sjPlot`. I want my prediction lines to have different linetypes and different colors.

The function includes a `colors` argument, and setting `colors` to `bw` will change `linetype`, but set `colors` to greyscale. This question is similar, but received no helpful answers: [Colored ribbons and different linetypes in sjPlot plot_model()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56060618/colored-ribbons-and-different-linetypes-in-sjplot-plot-model)

Examples:

Different `linetypes`, but not `colors`

```r
data(iris)
toy_model <- lm( Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Species, data=iris)

my_plot <- plot_model(toy_model, type=("pred"),
terms=c("Sepal.Width","Species"),
colors="bw")
```

Different `colors`, but not `linetypes`

```r
data(iris)
toy_model <- lm( Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Species, data=iris)

my_plot <- plot_model(toy_model, type=("pred"),
terms=c("Sepal.Width","Species"))
```

How can I get both different `colors` and different `linetypes`? In other words, I want something like this

[image: this]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`sjPlot` seems to be rather rigid when it comes to customisation, but there are ways around it. You can get the data from `ggpredict` (from `ggeffects` package) and customise the plot as usual in `ggplot`.

```
df <- ggpredict(toy_model, terms = c("Sepal.Width","Species"))
ggplot(df, aes(x, predicted)) + 
    geom_line(aes(linetype=group, color=group)) +
    geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=conf.low, ymax=conf.high, fill=group), alpha=0.15) +
    scale_linetype_manual(values = c("solid", "dashed", "dotted"))
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 5):

`plot_model` does allow `ggplot2` functions to adjust features of the plot.
You can easily change colors or linetypes.

```
library(sjPlot)
library(ggplot2)

data(iris)
toy_model <- lm( Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Species, data=iris)

#Use aes to change color or linetype
plot_model(toy_model, type=("pred"),
                      terms=c("Sepal.Width","Species")) + aes(linetype=group, color=group)

#Change color
plot_model(toy_model, type=("pred"),
                      terms=c("Sepal.Width","Species"), colors = "Set2") + aes(linetype=group, color=group)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMNxc.png)

Comment: Thank you, it solves part of the problem: one of my lines became dotted after using this solution. 1. How can I make it dashed instead? 2. How can I make dashed the other line, and not the one that gets dotted automatically?